# Spring Boot v2.0.0.M2 webflux and actuator

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-boot-actuator, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I'm not able to get `Actuator` work with `Spring Boot v2.0.0.M2` and `Netty`. The following dependencies are used in the `build.gradle`:

```
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    runtime "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"
```

I don't see information related to `Actuator` in the log files as well.
Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is patience :-)

This is scheduled for 2.0.0.M4 - in the meantime, you can subscribe [to one of the dedicated issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7972) and try things out with the SNAPSHOT version as soon as it's merged.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've googled it for an hour without any result.

Comment: No problem, there's a prototype in the works so hopefully you'll get your hands on it soon!