# How to make actuator work with webflux RouterFunction

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I have a web service I created previously with Request Mapping for mapping paths. Today I wanted to try the RouterFunction but none of my endpoints worked after I implemented it. I would get 404 not found on any endpoint.

I added EnableWebFlux annotation but then I started getting exceptions saying that there's another instance of a bean called requestMappingHandlerAdapter is loaded.

`The bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]`

I reviewed my dependencies and the web service started working properly once I removed spring-boot-actuator dependency.
Is there a way to bring back the spring-boot-actuator and still have the RouterFunction way of mapping endpoints working?

Comment: sry I didn't get, you wanna work with WebFlux or with SpringMVC? if with MVC - remove webflux annotation and webflux dependencies from classpath, if you wanna work with WebFlux on Netty -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311063/spring-boot-v2-0-0-m2-webflux-and-actuator. 
Hope it helps)

Comment: I did switch but then I had to remove actuator because it was using spring mvc. Is there a way to have webflux and actuator?

Comment: did you check link? but you know, you could use Tomcat nor Netty for webFlux, and I beelieve all be good.